# Concatenate env variables in environment.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to reduce some redundancy in my `environment.ts`, as many of my `env` variables start with the same. So what I wanted to do is this:

```
export const environment = {
    base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/',
    ws_base_url: this.base_url + 'ws',
    download_base_url: this.base_url + 'download'
}
```

Rather then:

```
export const environment = {
    base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/',
    ws_base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/ws',
    download_base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/download'
}
```

But when I use the `environment.ws_base_url` I don't get `//www.myWebsite.co.uk/ws`, but `undefined/ws`. I was just wondering if this is really not working or if I'm just missing something.

Comment: it's incredible how stupid is js.
Goddamn thanks I found this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just declare a variable outside the object:

```
const BASE_URL = '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/';

export const environment = {
    base_url: BASE_URL,
    ws_base_url: BASE_URL + 'ws',
    download_base_url: BASE_URL + 'download'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, js is an horrible language

Comment: But how `BASE_URL = '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/'` can be parametrized from the outside, then? If we are willing `//www.myWebsite.co.uk/` to become `//www.yourWebsite.tv/` without releasing another version of the application, how do we do? We loose the ability to change the value of ` base_url` later by making it a constant, the opposite of the environment goal.

Answer (score 2):

also, using ES5 getter should work

```
const environment = {
    base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/',
    get ws_base_url() {
      return this.base_url + 'ws';
    },
    get download_base_url() { 
      return this.base_url + 'download'
    }
}

console.log(environment)
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/gujecaleru/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

Since people are showing more than one way to do this I thought I might as well add another way.

```
environment = {}
environment.base_url= '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/'
environment.ws_base_url= environment.base_url + 'ws'
environment.download_base_url= environment.base_url + 'download'
```

Just something that I saw with your first code, it looks like you were missing a ',' in your environment declaration. Right after the declaration of the base_url:

```
base_url: '//www.myWebsite.co.uk/'
```